# Teams Graph API know when someone has joined an onlineMeeting

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to determine when someone has joined an online meeting. In Teams, you see the meeting coloured in purple when someone has started the meeting. I am looking for this information in the Graph API, either as a property, or a notification that I subscribe to.

I have tried a GET on onlineMeeting, but it doesn't include a status of whether the meeting has commenced. I have also looked at using the /communications/calls API thinking that it would include information about the onlineMeeting, but I can't find the ID of the onlineMeeting that calls would expect. I have tried the id of onlineMeeting, but I get an UnknownError.

I have also tried looking at the chat information to see if it updates a status in the chat when a user joins a session - but nothing is there in the chat messages.

I just want to know if someone is in the lobby so that I can update the status of my application to say that someone is waiting.

Comment: You can take a look at [list participants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-list-participants?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) in call object

Comment: Thanks.  What is the id I use to call this api. It doesn't seem to work when I use the id of the online meeting.

Comment: it should be your call id

Comment: Something in this format "id": "bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbc_19:meeting_MTxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxTFh@thread.v2",
   "